# Why is ksm() so strange?

Tags: 8

I have an Embed View on a custom content entity to be used with `views_embed_view()`.
I'm trying to understand how contextual filters work on this view.
So, I use Devel 'Run php' to execute the function containing this:

```
$view = views_embed_view('services', 'embed_2', someparameter);
```

And in my module, I have coded this:

```
function sel_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
  if ($view->id() == 'services' && $view->current_display == 'embed_2') {
    ksm(something);
  }
}
```

When `something` is `$query->where`, I get the expected result:
[image]
But when `something` is `$query` (to have more information on the query), I am redirected to Drupal installation!
[image] 
Any idea why?

If I can't make `ksm($query)` work, where can I find documentation on the `query` object (methods, properties)?

Comment: Use xdebug. Superior.

Comment: try dpm and also, make sure the user role has access to ksm or the "access kin" permission.  And of course xdebug will the best option.

Comment: when I execute dpm($query), i get this:
`The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error: Cannot access protected property Drupal\Core\Utility\Error::$blacklistFunctions in Drupal\Core\Utility\Error::getLastCaller() (line 116 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Utility/Error.php).`
Being Admin (user1) of this site, I assume I have access to anything.

Comment: Being user 1 has nothing to do with being able to access/read protected/private properties of objects.

Comment: I didn't know that. I have the 'Administrator' role and if I look at 'People>Permissions' tab, all rows are ticked. Is there another place where rights are handled?

Comment: It doesn't matter... that relates to language syntax and rules, not the application. You're trying to directly access a protected property as the error states, that is not possible. You need to use a getter and one may not exist for that. `Error: Cannot access protected property `

Comment: try `ksm($query->__toString());` or `ksm($query->arguments());`

Comment: I tried and got `Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\Sql::__toString()`and 
`Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\Sql::arguments()`.
I digged a little and found that in `mysite/web/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/query/Sql.php`, the public properties are: $distinct, $fields, $groupby, $having, $orderby, $relationships, $tables, $tags, $where. I don't know how to have a more "global" source of information:-(